# Vectorized entry-wise logsumexp in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization

Given a 2D `numpy` array `A` and a 1D array `c`, I would like to compute the 2D array `B` with entries 
`B[i, j] = scipy.special.logsumexp(np.append(c, A[i, j]))`.

Could I do this in a vectorized manner instead of using a double for-loop?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use simply `np.log(np.sum(np.exp(c)) + np.exp(A))`?

**[Update based on Paul Panzer's comment]**

```
_c = np.broadcast_to(c, (*A.shape, *c.shape))
B = scipy.special.logsumexp(np.append(_c, A[...,np.newaxis], axis=-1), axis=-1)
```

Comment: The whole point of `logsumexp` is to work around overflow in the `exp`.

Comment: That tuple-unpacking-repacking is kind of cute.

Answer (score 2):

To mimic the behavior of `logsumexp` all you have to do is subtract the `max` of its argument (check the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.0.0/scipy/special/_logsumexp.py#L8-L127)) before taking the `exp, sum, log` and then re-add it at the very end. Thus you could do something like:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import special
>>> 
>>> A = np.random.uniform(900, 1100, (4, 4))
>>> c = np.random.uniform(950, 1050, (7,))
>>> 
>>> cm = np.max(c)
>>> mask = A > cm
>>> B = np.empty_like(A)
>>> B[mask] = A[mask] + np.log(np.exp(np.subtract.outer(cm, A[mask])).sum(axis=-1) + 1)
>>> B[~mask] = cm + np.log(np.exp(c - cm).sum() + np.exp(A[~mask] - cm))
>>> 
# compute via logsumexp for reference
>>> cA = np.empty((8, 4, 4))
>>> cA[:-1] = c[:, None, None]
>>> cA[-1] = A
>>> special.logsumexp(cA, axis=0)
array([[ 1048.88855012,  1048.88854955,  1069.83524808,  1048.88854955],
       [ 1048.88854955,  1048.88854955,  1048.88877212,  1048.93142975],
       [ 1048.88854955,  1067.59166572,  1048.88854955,  1069.78737913],
       [ 1048.88854955,  1048.88854955,  1098.61910373,  1072.76058998]])
>>> B
array([[ 1048.88855012,  1048.88854955,  1069.83524809,  1048.88854955],
       [ 1048.88854955,  1048.88854955,  1048.88877212,  1048.93142975],
       [ 1048.88854955,  1067.59166572,  1048.88854955,  1069.78737914],
       [ 1048.88854955,  1048.88854955,  1098.61910374,  1072.76058999]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually, I was wondering if it's possible to broadcast `A` to a 3D array `Ac` of shape `(A.shape[0], A.shape[1], len(c))`   (`len(c)` is very small in my case) and then simply apply `logsumexp(Ac, axis=-1)`? I couldn't figure out exactly how to implement this broadcasting though...

Comment: @Hilbert. Sure `Ac = np.empty(A.shape + (len(c)+1,), dtype=A.dtype)` `Ac[..., 0] = A` `Ac[..., 1:] = c`. Didn't test it but think it should work.